# Swift, is it possible to use SF Symbols in Navigation Bar title?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, titlebar

Wondering how I can use SF Symbols as View Controller title. Is it possible to do so?

```
    viewController.title = [somehow want to use an SF Symbol here]
```

Comment: You can try and see it yourself whether it's possible or not, fairly easy to test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do that using imageView and SFSymbol

```
let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(systemName: "gear"))
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        navigationItem.titleView = imageView
```